# Get values from two apis into two different Observable and perform some operation

Tags: ios, swift, rx-swift

I have two independent observables. I need to perform some operation when both of them are complete and each of them provided an array.

```
let myObj1Array = myObj1Manager.getMyObj1List()//returns Observable<[MyObj1]>
let myObj2Array = myObj2Manager.getMyObj2List()//returns Observable<[MyObj2]>
```

Now I need to compare values of myObj1Array and myObj2Array and on the basis of that create another array using values from both arrays. I know how to subscribe 1 variable but not sure how to observe completion of two different arrays.

**Edit:**
I also tried following but I get values only from first array:

```
let myObj1Array = myObj1Manager.getMyObj1List()
        let myObj2Array = myObj1Array.flatMap { _ in myObj2Manager.getMyObj2List() }
        Observable.combineLatest(myObj1Array, myObj2Array)
        .subscribe(onNext: { (sss, sds) in
            print(sss)
        })
        .addDisposableTo(disposeBag)
```

I am actually kind of clueless about how to handle such scenario.

**Edit2:**
function to get the observables in first array:

```
func getMyObj1List() -> Observable<[MyObj1]> {
        return Observable.create { observer -> Disposable in
            self.specialsRest.getMyObj1List { response, error in
                if let error = error {
                    observer.onError(Exception(error))
                    return
                }
                guard let saleItems = MyObj1.decode(data: response?.data) else {
                    observer.onError(Exception("Could not decode specials!"))
                    return
                }
                queueBackground.async {
                   
                    observer.onNext(saleItems)
                    observer.onCompleted()
                }

            }
            return Disposables.create { self.specialsRest.cancel() }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you illustrate the code where you 1) set your observables (which looks like your first block but also looks like it is returning something) and 2) where you get data back from the observations? `let myObj1Array = myObj1Manager.getMyObj1List()` is this setting the observation, or retrieving data back? I guess I don't see where you are asynchronously getting the data back, i.e. when the observer is called with the data.

Answer (score 1):

DispatchGroup is probably the way to go here.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/dispatch/dispatchgroup

> When all work items finish executing, the group executes its completion handler. You can also wait synchronously for all tasks in the group to finish executing.

```
var dg:DispatchGroup = DispatchGroup()

//Wherever you start your observables.
//Start Observer1
dg.enter()

//Start Observer2
dg.enter()

...
...
...

//Wherever you retrieve data
SomeAsyncFuncForObserver1 {
    //Get Data
    dg.leave()
}

SomeAsyncFuncForObserver2 {
    //Get Data
    dg.leave()
}

dg.notify(queue: .main) {
    print("all finished.")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to use `zip` instead of `combineLatest`. From the [docs](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/combinelatest.html)

> The CombineLatest operator behaves in a similar way to Zip, but while
> Zip emits items only when each of the zipped source Observables have
> emitted a previously unzipped item, CombineLatest emits an item
> whenever any of the source Observables emits an item (so long as each
> of the source Observables has emitted at least one item).

```
Observable
    .zip(myObj1Array, myObj2Array)
    .subscribe(onNext: { (sss, sds) in
        print(sss)
    })
    .addDisposableTo(disposeBag)
```

Comment: Assuming that `myObj1Array` and `myObj2Array` both emit only one value and then complete, `zip` and `combineLatest` behave identically. They only behave differently if at least one of the inputs emits more than one next event.